# Android SDK is not installig

Tags: android, android-studio, ionic-framework, android-sdk-tools

I tried to install Android SDK in my system. I set the environment variable `ANDROID_HOME`using system settings but when I am trying to run a command `android` in my terminal it gives an error:

> 'android' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

I tried to install via android studio too but not installing. Please suggested what to do.

Comment: i am using Windows 10 and solution is not working for me.

Comment: Android command is deprecated with latest android sdk. you should be able to execute the android.bat after navigating to the tools directory